# How can i make laravel form::file selection to show me my uploaded images?

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I want to make it posible within my editing form to choose or change the image of my product. But i want it to give me the posiblity of choosing from my already uploaded images in my public directory or to upload a new one.

I know if i do this:

```
{!! Form::file('img', $contentimg, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

It wil allow me to choose a file from my computer. But how do i get it to show me my already uploaded images.

Comment: You would need additional functionality to display and select previously uploaded images as that is not a default part of Laravel.

Comment: perhaps a drop down list right above the file upload field that shows all local images?

Comment: Any tips or idea of something similar to what i want to do? Cuase i have no idea what to do or search for.

Comment: You will need to use some javascript. id the file input then trigger on upload event to display it on a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it already had an uploaded image, just check if exist then display right below the form field

```
{!! Form::file('img', $contentimg, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
@if($contentimg->img)
<img src="{{$contentimg->img}}" class="" ... />
@endif
```

There is no need to do complicated stuffs.